# How to import cwac camera library

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac, cwac-camera

I am trying to import [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) project in my android studio version **2.1.2**

But I am getting below error couldn't solve it .

**Error :**

> Error:(12, 13) Failed to resolve: com.commonsware.cwac:camera:0.6.12
>   Show
>   in File
> Show in
>   Project Structure dialog

Any help would be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: That library has been discontinued. I no longer support this library. The instructions provided in the `README` and the below answer should work.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried many times it didnt :(

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any other library with this feature or nearly? Or any suggestion from your side?? and [Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393597/video-capturing-in-square-frame-like-social-apps-fb-instagram-twitter-do) this for what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

please use this way.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:camera:0.6.+'
}
```

Comment: You must also include maven central repo like so : `mavenCentral()`

Answer (score 0):

You must also include maven central repo like so : `mavenCentral()` so that you won't break your exisiting dependencies

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
    }

    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:camera:0.6.+'
}
```